# Update 'duration' of .animate function within the 'onChange'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate, fabricjs

I'm trying to improve an animation that I've been working on where things move across the screen.
Currently the object moves at a set speed and has no variance.

I'm trying to include two features that will ultimately end up doing the same thing; changing the speed of the animated object.

I'd like the user to be able to change the speed and also for the object to slow down or speed up depending on where it is on the screen.

I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place as currently I've been unable to update the duration once the animation loop has started.  I first thought I could replace the number with a function that would return an int.  This works in that the value of 'speed' changes but the animate loop is not updated.

Any help is hugely appreciated, thanks.

Code snippets below.

```
function moveObj () {

//initially the duration was set here.  I understand that will not work as the animation is only
//being called once.

//animation process
obj.animate('top', '+=' + canvas.height, {
    duration: speedOfObj(0),
    abort: function () {
    },//end abort callback
    onChange: function () {
        //testing only//
        speedOfObj(1000);
}

//test function to see what the results would be. speed changes when called within the on change but  the animation is not affected.
function speedOfObj(modifier){
    var speed = 10000 / (new Number(speedControl.value));
    if(modifier == 0){
        console.log("speed: "+speed);
        return speed;
    }else{
        speed *= modifier;
        console.log("speedBBBB: "+speed);
        return speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Providing your fiddle ! may more help full !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a jQuery animation is off and running, it's pretty much off on its own.  If you want to change how it works, you can `.stop(true)` it and then start up a new animation that starts again from where it is now at your new speed.

It's also possible to implement a custom step function in the animation that might takes some queues for how to work from outside influences that can change during the animation, but I think that would end being much more complicated than just stopping the original animation and starting a new one that moves at the newly desired speed.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tzxca/

Comment: ah, that does pose a problem.  When using the .stop that you mentioned, is it possible to make it look seamless?  Ny that I mean, hen the obj is at a specific point I'd like it to slow down and not judder if you know what I mean.  Possible?

Comment: If you are using a linear easing, the `.stop()` should not be noticeable except that the speed would change.

Comment: I just noticed your edit, I thin that would be overkill although without it slowing or changing speed I'm kind of hitting head against a wall.  DOn't suppose you have a sample or fiddle of how the stop is implemented at all?

Comment: That'd be fantastic, thanks!  I think I understand what you mean, I just had a peek at the method in the query docs and I guess if I were to run the animation, then stop, change the duration variable and then run the animation again I could give the impression of a fluid animation whilst still changing the speed.  I guess the objects position would be saved as well so hopefully it might be fairly straightforward...famous last words.

Comment: Such a legend! :D Thank you for your help and time, much appreciated.

Comment: Just another quick thank you.  I was able to implement what you suggested using the fiddle (revision 1 :)) although I'm unable to call .stop() on the object but it still runs fine.  I think the stop issue may be because it's not a div or html element that I've targeted ith query but a fabric object instead.  Thank you though, this has enabled me to extend the idea further using those functions (slower / faster) -